# How Do I Implement Operations Into A Stacked List

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on implementing an RPN calculator into a stack. The numbers push into the stack just fine, however, when trying to do operations within the stack, it seems as though there is a hiccup somewhere.

For example; when pushing 5 and 6 into the stack, the output is then **5, 6,**. However upon entering **+** into the stack, it returns with **5, [object Object][object Object],** instead of **5, 11,**. How would I go about implementing future operations correctly to work within the stack and its contents?

```js
var Node = function(_content) {
  this.next = null;
  this.last = null;
  this.content = _content;
};

var Stack = function() {
  this.top = null;
  this.bottom = null;
  this.push = function(_content) {
    if (this.bottom == null) {
      this.bottom = new Node(_content);
      this.top = this.bottom;
      return this;
    }

    var myNode = new Node(_content);
    myNode.last = this.top;
    this.top.next = myNode;
    this.top = myNode
  }

  this.pop = function() {
    if (this.bottom == null) {
      alert("The stack is empty")
      return null
    }

    if (this.bottom == this.top) {
      this.top = this.bottom
      this.top.last = null
      return this.top
    }

    var testStack = this.top
    this.top = this.top.last
    this.top.next = null
    return testStack
  }

  this.toString = function() {
    var myString = ""
    var node = this.bottom
    while (node != null) {
      myString += node.content + ", "
      node = node.next;
    }
    return myString
  }
}

function deleteScreen() {
  var n = ""
  document.getElementById("value").value = ""
}

var stack = new Stack()
var x
var y
var z
var result
var input

function push() {
  input = document.getElementById("value").value
  if (input === "" || input === " ") {
    alert("Please enter a number!")
  }
  stack.push(input)
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = stack.toString();
  deleteScreen()
  if (input == '+') {
    var x = stack.pop()
    var y = stack.pop()
    stack.push(x + y)
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = stack.toString();
  }
};
```

```html
<input style="width: 100px" type="textbox" id='value' />
<input type="button" id="assign" value="Insert Number Into Stack" onclick="push()" />
<p id="output">
</p>
```

Comment: Sjouldn't `+ 5 6` be just `11`, not `5 11`?

Comment: Also, your `pop` returns the nodes themselves, not their value. `x + y` will not work because you're adding together two objects.

Comment: @VLAZ, my thought process was to leave the initial entry there, pop the second entry then push the operation out to the list. Not sure if this makes sense in concept, would it be easier to replace it entirely?

Comment: I mean, if you're going to perform the operation, then the whole sub-expression should be replaced with the result. Otherwise entering `5` -> `6` -> `+` leaves you with an extra `5` which is already part of the result. Unless you want to keep adding "first number entered" for some reason. I'm checking if that's the intention or a mistake.

Comment: @VLAZ - Sorry for the misunderstanding, my thought process was wrong when trying to work through this. You are correct, the 5 being entered would not be apart of the result, the 10 would be pushed to the stack.

Comment: OK. I believe your stack implementation is wrong. Using `pop` when there is only one element in the stack will *retain that element*: https://jsbin.com/xefatur/edit?js,console. In general, your stack is more of a list. It has a `push` and `pop` which is normal for a stack but all the elements are linked nodes. Which you also return raw - normally `pop` should just give back the value that was put in.

Comment: It seems really unnecessarily complicated for such a simple thing....